# WPF TextBox's value updates while I am typing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, multibinding

I have bound two TextBoxes in TwoWay Mode to a `double?` value via `DoubleConvertor`.
And values update while I am typing.
1st case. If I type a double value in the first TB, switch to the second, and press an invalid symbol, the value is erased by the update.
2nd case. If I enter too many digits, the tail digits are corrected to zero.

```
public class DoubleConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is not double doubleValue)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        return doubleValue.ToString("0.########", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public object? ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is not string stringValue)
        {
            return null;
        }
        
        var parsed = double.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var doubleValue);
        return parsed ? doubleValue : null;
    }
}
```

The way how I bind to the `double?` value:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource DoubleConvertor}"
                 Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

How to make it not update the text field while typing?
There is the source code: [GitHub](https://github.com/dgzargo/WpfTest).

Comment: What you describe here is this is the expected bahaviour. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Felix, I added it.

Comment: One mor thing: What actually stops you from directly binding to a property of type `double` without using any converter?

Comment: i would suggest you fix your converter rather than worry about stopping the control updating, if you convert the value and its not a double instead of unsetting the value, remove the invalid char from the string

Comment: @Felix My actual converter is more complicated than `ToString` and `TryParse`

Answer (score 0):

The `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` defines that the binding is updated on every change of the property (e.g. on every char that is input).

If you want the update to only happen when the teyt box loses focus (i.e. another elemtent is focused), you need to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`.

Your text box could then look like this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource DoubleConvertor}"
                 Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't fix the issue. We have lesser updates but it still updates incorrectly typed field value.

Comment: What do you think about my convertor? Could there be an issue?

Comment: Well, in the `Convert()` part of your converter, there is a check weather `value` is of type `double` (which is necessary to bind to a double). If your `value` is not of type `double`, The value of the property is set to be empty. Validation might help here, but I am not very familiar with that.

Comment: To make things more clear (as to what error still persists), I suppose that you describe the remaining issue in this question or in another question. (To find a solution, it would be necessary to know the problem that persists after the change to `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`.

Comment: In the Convert() part, I don't want to set the value of the property. I want it to stay unchanged. How to do that?

Comment: I am not sure weather that is possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244994/discussion-between-felix-and-dgzargo).